# Plotly shows wrong data of Gantt chart when using subplot

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I have the Gantt chart which is plotted by px.timeline is working well like below image. As it would be overlapping each other and could be easier to review with transparent color as well.

[image]

But when I would like to add it as subplot, it shows something wrong as Red window is gone, like below image

[image]

This is full code, you can comment and uncomment 2 rows here to see the different

```
# fig = trace_1 #uncomment this line to see the difference
fig.add_trace(trace_1.data[0], row=1, col=1) #comment this line to see the difference
```

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Task': ['Task 1', 'Task 2', 'Task 3', 'Task 4', 'Task 5', 'Task 6'],
    'Start': [pd.Timestamp('2022-01-01'), pd.Timestamp('2022-01-02'), pd.Timestamp('2022-01-03'), pd.Timestamp('2022-01-03'), pd.Timestamp('2022-01-05'), pd.Timestamp('2022-01-04')],
    'Finish': [pd.Timestamp('2022-01-02'), pd.Timestamp('2022-01-04'), pd.Timestamp('2022-01-05'), pd.Timestamp('2022-01-08'), pd.Timestamp('2022-01-06'), pd.Timestamp('2022-01-07')],
    'Resource': ['Resource 1', 'Resource 2', 'Resource 3', 'Resource 4', 'Resource 4', 'Resource 4'],
    'Type': ['Type_Blue', 'Type_Blue', 'Type_Red', 'Type_Blue', 'Type_Blue', 'Type_Red']
})

fig = make_subplots(rows=2, shared_xaxes=True)

trace_1 = px.timeline(df, x_start='Start', x_end='Finish', y='Resource',
                      color='Type', color_discrete_map={'Type_Blue': 'blue', 'Type_Red': 'red'}, opacity=0.2)

# fig = trace_1 #uncomment this line to see the difference
fig.add_trace(trace_1.data[0], row=1, col=1) #comment this line to see the difference

fig.update_yaxes(autorange="reversed") 
fig.update_layout(title='Timeline Subplots')
fig.update_xaxes(type='date')
fig.show()
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graph created by express consists of two bars as its internal structure. Since the first data is the one specified in the subplot, only one is displayed. Also, express has a facet function, so it is easiest to specify it. I will answer that example as well.

```
fig = make_subplots(rows=2, shared_xaxes=True)
trace_1 = px.timeline(df, x_start='Start', x_end='Finish', y='Resource',
                      color='Type', color_discrete_map={'Type_Blue': 'blue', 'Type_Red': 'red'}, opacity=0.2)


# fig = trace_1 #uncomment this line to see the difference
fig.add_trace(trace_1.data[0], row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(trace_1.data[1], row=2, col=1)

fig.update_yaxes(autorange="reversed") 
fig.update_layout(title='Timeline Subplots')
fig.update_xaxes(type='date')
fig.show()
```

[image]

**Timeline ＆ Pie chart**

```
df['Count'] = 1

fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2, specs=[[{'type': 'xy'},{'type': 'pie'}]])

trace_1 = px.timeline(df, x_start='Start', x_end='Finish', y='Resource',
                      color='Type', color_discrete_map={'Type_Blue': 'blue', 'Type_Red': 'red'}, opacity=0.2)
trace_2 = px.pie(df, values='Count', names='Resource')

fig.add_trace(trace_1.data[0], row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(trace_1.data[1], row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(trace_2.data[0], row=1, col=2)

fig.update_yaxes(autorange="reversed") 
fig.update_layout(title='Timeline Subplots')
fig.update_xaxes(type='date')
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I see, the issue here is trace_1.data has array for that, so when I make it to the same row, col position, it would be stacked `fig.add_trace(trace_1.data[0], row=1, col=1)` and `fig.add_trace(trace_1.data[1], row=1, col=1) ` it looks better. 

But there is no way to let Type_Blue and Type_Red overlapping each other? There is an usecase that blue is a time window and the red tasks should be placed within the blue.

Comment: Isn't your goal to separate the graphs, not to stack them? I can't imagine the expected output. Perhaps you want to vary the width (height) by category instead of the same width?

Comment: Actually my goal is like this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/QONeO.png . The red and blue would be overlapping each other. The purpose to create the subplot is I want the second row will store another like pie chart.

Comment: If the ultimate goal is to subplot different graphs, then we have put them side by side because it looks better side by side in terms of layout with the timeline and pie chart. For reference.